# Rolling mean with different window length

Tags: r, data.table

How can I calculate a two-month rolling mean, if the two-months windows are not of equal length? Preferably in `datatable`. Sample code:

```
set.seed(24)
test <- data.table(x = rnorm(762),time=seq(as.Date("1988/03/15"), as.Date("1990/04/15"), "day"))
```

So here, the first mean would be from 1988/03/15 until 1988/04/30, the second one from 1988/04/01 until 1988/05/31, and so on. The data availability in each month can be of different length, by intention.

Comment: Do you mean for example, first value will be the mean from 15/03 until 15/05; then 16/04 until 16/05 and so on?

Comment: Thanks for the question. No, I meant the first one from 15/03 until 30/04. For the first month, there are just not as many days available. I edited the question.

Comment: What is the second value?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909528/compute-all-fixed-window-averages-with-dplyr-and-rcpproll/49913886#49913886

Comment: In terms of speed I can recommend `RcppRoll`. Worked wonders for bigger data

Comment: Thanks all. Please see the edited question for the dates over which the mean should be calculated. The intention was just to create a variable rolling window. I currently can't find any solution where this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `yearmon` column and then summarize the sum and length of `x` by `yearmon`.
Finally divide a rolling sum over `x` by a rolling sum over the length `N`.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

Means <- test[, yearmon := as.yearmon(time)][
   , list(x = sum(x), N = .N), by = "yearmon"][
   , list(yearmon, mean = rollsumr(x, 2, fill = NA) / rollsumr(N, 2, fill = NA))]
```

Alternately convert `test` to a zoo object, sum `x` and the length by yearmon, calculate the rolling sum of both x and n and divide giving a zoo object with the year/months and means.  See `?fortify.zoo` if you would like to convert that to a data frame.

```
z <- cbind(x = read.zoo(test, index = "time"), n = 1)
zym <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, sum)
transform(rollsumr(zym, 2), mean = x / n)
```

### Note

Input used is:

```
set.seed(24)
test <- data.table(x = rnorm(762), time=seq(as.Date("1988/03/15"), 
                          as.Date("1990/04/15"), "day"))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine. The only thing that could be improved is to not create a new datatable (in the above case 'Means'). Ideally I would like to create only a new column in the existing datatable. Is this also possible?

Comment: Not clear.  What should that column contain?  Do you want the mean of the two months repeated for each day in the second month of the window?  Do you want it to appear on the last day of the month with all other values NA?  Please calculate example output by hand and show it in the question so its clear what you want.

Comment: Hm I guess you are right there would be a lot of repetition, but my idea was to have indeed the mean of the two months repeated in both months, or in the second month only. Would be nice to see if it is possible, but the solution right now is fine already.

Comment: If you want to repeat the mean for each row in the second month then after running the data.table code above run `merge(test, Means, by = "yearmon")`